# React native websocket not working in release mode

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket

So I'm trying to make a react native app that communicates with a websocket c# server. Everything works fine in debug mode but when I create a release apk and I try to run it it just doesn't work. Can someone help me please?

I tried seeing the websocket status and it returned 3, so it just says that is not connected.

```
export default class Socket {
  socket: WebSocket;
  constructor(indirizzo: string) {
    this.socket = new WebSocket(indirizzo);
    this.socket.onopen = () => {
      console.log('Mi sono connesso');
    };
  }

  Disconnetti() {
    this.socket.close();
  }

  Manda(nomeEvento: string, messaggio: any) {
    
    try {
      this.socket.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          nomeEvento: nomeEvento,
          username: messaggio.username,
          password: messaggio.password,
          codice: messaggio.codice,
          movimento: messaggio.movimento,
        }),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  Ricevi(nomeEvento: string, callback: (risposta: any) => void): any {
    this.socket.onmessage = e => {
      try {
        let risposta = JSON.parse(e.data);
        if (risposta.nomeEvento === nomeEvento ) {  //Forse dovrei fare una lista di eventi e controllare se l'evento è presente nella lista 
          callback(risposta.messaggio);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: The code you posted does not work because...oh wait you posted NO code; please do so with what you have tried.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I'm sorry, I posted my code now

Comment: Just a super quick comment without any real thought here try changing `e` here to `event` and `ex`  `this.socket.onmessage = e => {
      try {
        let risposta = JSON.parse(e.data);
        if (risposta.nomeEvento === nomeEvento ) {  //Forse dovrei fare una lista di eventi e controllare se l'evento è presente nella lista 
          callback(risposta.messaggio);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your config.urlServer is not an HTTP endpoint but should be HTTPS. Latest RN versions target recent Android SDK that blocks insecure HTTP connections automatically.
Please add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in tag in android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml